# Рандомное заполнение массива (как жеребьевка в футболе)

Tags: javascript, массивы, angularjs, сортировка, frontend

HTML код берет 2 значения, число груп и число команд в группах.

```
<div class="league-left-settings"></a>
        <h3>Число групп</h3>
        <input class="input" type="number" ng-model="vm.groupNumber" ng-class="{error: vm.groupError, success: vm.groupSuccess}" ng-change="vm.check('groups')">
        <h3>Команд в группе</h3>
        <input class="input" type="number" ng-model="vm.teamNumber" ng-class="{error: vm.teamError, success: vm.teamSuccess}"  ng-change="vm.check('teams')">
        <h3 ng-if="vm.total">Общее число команд: {{vm.groupNumber * vm.teamNumber}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="league-left-teams" ng-if="vm.allteams">
        <h3>Команды</h3>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Название команды" ng-repeat="team in vm.teamsArr track by $index" ng-model="vm.teamsArr[$index]">
    </div>
    <div class="league-left-button">
        <button class="button" ng-click="vm.generate()">Генерировать</button>
    </div>
```

После ввода чисел, заполняется массив vm.teamsArr названиями команд.

```
for(var i = 0; i < vm.groupNumber; i++){
    vm.groupsArr[i] = {
        group: vm.groupName[i],
        teams: new Array(vm.teamNumber)
    };
}
```

Этот код подготавливает массив всех групп, который содержит объекты в котором массив команд(которые будут в группе) и название группы.

Теперь мой вопрос: Как заполнить все группы командами, вытаскивая их рандомно с массива vm.teamsArr и вставлять рандомно в vm.groupsArr(точнее в массив teams).

```
Всю сортировку и жеребьевку должна выполнять функция vm.generate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял вашу проблему. Но если правильно, то предлагаю такое решение

```js
for(var i = 0; i < vm.groupNumber; i++){
  vm.groupsArr[i] = {
    group: vm.groupName[i],
    teams: []
  };

  // выполняем операцию случайной выборки групп
  // требуемое кол-во раз (vm.teamNumber)
  for (var j = 0; j < vm.teamNumber; j++) {
    // генерируем случайный индекс, основываясь на
    // длине массива групп
    var rand = Math.random() * vm.teamsArr.length,
        // округляем до целого числа и выбираем
        team = vm.teamsArr[Math.floor(rand)];
        // если нужно, что бы группы не повторялись
        // тогда их нужно вырезать из массива
        // team = vm.teamsArr.splice(Math.floor(rand), 1);

        // добавляем в команду группы
    vm.groupsArr[i].teams.push(team);
  }
}
```

Алгоритм такой. А уж какая функция его должна выполнять решайте сами

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало!